# Selecting rows if the total sum of a row is equal to X

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that holds items and their "weight" and it looks like this:

```
items
-----

id          weight
----------  ----------
1           1
2           5
3           2
4           9
5           8
6           4
7           1
8           2
```

What I'm trying to get is a group where the sum(weight) is exactly X, while honouring the order in which were inserted.

For example, if I were looking for X = 3, this should return:

```
id          weight
----------  ----------
1           1
3           2
```

Even though the sum of ids 7 and 8 is 3 as well.

Or if I were looking for X = 7 should return

```
id          weight
----------  ----------
2           5
3           2
```

Although the sum of the ids 1, 3 and 6 also sums 7.

I'm kind of lost in this problem and haven't been able to come up with a query that does at least something similar, but thinking this problem through, it might get extremely complex for the RDBMS to handle. Could this be done with a query? if not, what's the best way I can query the database to get the minimum amount of data to work with?

**Edit**: As Twelfth says, I need to return the sum, regardless of the amount of rows it returns, so if I were to ask for X = 20, I should get:

```
id          weight
----------  ----------
1           1
3           2
4           9
5           8
```

Comment: is it 2 numbers in the sum?  or if you gave x = 20 you might get 1,3,4,5 (I think that adds to 20)?

Comment: Well, I'm looking only to match the X, regardless of the amount of rows that it return, so yes, if I were to give it 20, it should return 1, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: Had to ask...there is a decent solution if it's always summing just two number using a self join.  However, if it goes beyond that...see Jean-Bernard's answer below

Comment: How big is this table?

Comment: Also any chance you might be able to use a different database just for this one task?

Comment: It's actually rather small. There could be 200~400 rows at any given time, it's rare for it to grow pass that point.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia: I'm pretty much open to any solution at this point, so I think it's feasible to add another table for this task.

Comment: A different database I mean, namely one that has window functions

Comment: @BrianDeMilia: I'm kinda stuck with mysql for the time being D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could turn out to be very difficult in sql. What you're attempting to do is solve the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Solving), which is non-trivial.

> The knapsack problem is interesting from the perspective of computer science for many reasons:

- The decision problem form of the knapsack problem (Can a value of at least V be achieved without exceeding the weight W?) is NP-complete, thus there is no possible algorithm both correct and fast (polynomial-time) on all cases, unless P=NP.
- While the decision problem is NP-complete, the optimization problem is NP-hard, its resolution is at least as  difficult as the decision problem, and there is no known polynomial algorithm which can tell, given a solution, whether it is optimal (which would mean that there is no solution with a larger, thus solving the decision problem NP-complete).
- There is a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm using dynamic programming.
- There is a fully polynomial-time approximation scheme, which uses the pseudo-polynomial time algorithm as a subroutine, described below.
- Many cases that arise in practice, and "random instances" from some distributions, can nonetheless be solved exactly.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should stop caring either for correctness or speed, ditch SQL to solve this and do some heuristics to see if I can get something closer to what I'm looking for.